# Get the month and year now then count the number of rows that are older then 12 months in SQL/Classic ASP

Tags: sql, asp-classic, sql-server-2012

I know this one is pretty easy but I've always had a nightmare when it comes to comparing dates in SQL please can someone help me out with this, thanks.

I need to get the month and year of now then compare it to a date stored in a DB.

Time Format in the DB:

2015-08-17 11:10:14.000

I need to compare the month and year with now and if its > 12 months old I will increment a count. I just need the number of rows where this argument is true.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a [datetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819(v=sql.110).aspx) field.

You can use the [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794(v=sql.110).aspx) function, which takes the kind of "crossed boundaries", the start date and the end date.
Your boundary is the month because you are only interested in year and month, not days, so you can use the `month` macro.
Your start time is the value stored in the table's row.
Your end time is now. You can get system time selecting [SYSDATETIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630353(v=sql.110).aspx) function.

So, assuming your table is called `mtable` and the datetime object is stored in its `date` field, you simply have to query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mtable where DATEDIFF(month, mtable.date, (SELECT SYSDATETIME())) > 12
```

Comment: Thanks, I literally figured this out a few minutes ago I ended up using the DATEADD function: cDate = DATEADD("m", -12, now)
sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (Time >='" & cDate & "')))"